# Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)

Tags: json, swift, xcode, decode, moya

I have an error: **Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)**

I use Moya and have JSON:

```
"buttons" : [
  {
    "name" : "chat",
    "title" : "Сообщения",
    "active" : true
  },
  {
    "title" : "Управление заявкой",
    "active" : true,
    "name" : "posterRecordActions",
    "actions" : {
      "name" : "cancelPosterRecord",
      "title" : "Отменить заявку",
      "active" : true
    }
  }
]
```

My Struct:

```
struct Record: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let title: String
        @FailableURL var image: URL?
        let statusTitle: String
        let statusColorName: String
        let price: Int
        let startTime: Int
        let description: String?
        let placeTitle: String
        let members: [Members]
        let rules: String?
        let recordForm: [String]
        let buttons: [API.Posters.RequestButtons]

 struct RequestButtons: Codable {
        let name: RequestButtonName
        let title: String
        let active: Bool?
        let actions: [RequestButtons]?
        let paymentLink: String?
        let paymentContext: String?
        let value: String?
        let badge: Int?
    }
```

I think, they problems with **actions** inside **buttons**, but I can't resolve this(

Comment: Most likely it’s an issue with what root (top) level object type you are using in your decoding call.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry, I don't understand what did you mean(

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are decoding the downloaded json and you pass the type to decode into. This type is what I think is the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

`Actions` in your JSON is **NOT** array, it's a dictionary.

Change your struct like below code:

```
 struct RequestButtons: Codable {
    ...
    let actions: RequestButtons?
    ...
}
```

Additionally, I suggest to read swift API design for your naming convention; [API Design Guidelines](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming/)

For example `RequestButtons` have to be `RequestButton` or `actions` in your case have to be `action`, because they're not plural